# PyCharm - getting cursor position from shell

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

When I close and reopen a PyCharm project, the last file and cursor position (line number and number of characters from line-start) is preserved, so it's obviously being saved somewhere.

Is there a way I can access this cursor position data from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

The whole information about current project's session is stored in `.idea/workspace.xml` file. I didn't checked it thoroughly, but here is the solution:

```
$ xmllint .idea/workspace.xml --xpath '//project/component[@name="FileEditorManager"]/leaf/file[@leaf-file-name="PUT_YOUR_FILENAME_HERE"]/entry/provider/state/caret/@line'
line="501"
$ xmllint .idea/workspace.xml --xpath '//project/component[@name="FileEditorManager"]/leaf/file[@leaf-file-name="PUT_YOUR_FILENAME_HERE"]/entry/provider/state/caret/@column'
column="12"
```